# Divergence of a vector field and differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

I just started learning differential geometry, and my knowledge on exterior algebra is basically nonexistent. While reading about the Invariant Stokes theorem, I encountered this lemma:

> [If **F** = (*f1, f2, f3*) is a vector field in ℝ3, then div(**F**) = ∇ · **F** = ∗d(∗**F**♭)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nexmW.png)

The document where I found this does not provide a definition of *, nor of ♭. I'm having a hard time digesting all this notation... What do these symbols mean? Is * related to the wedge product? If so, how? What does this mean in terms of differential forms? 
Thank you for your time! (Please assume very little previous knowledge from me)
[Source](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ej9shaw/Invariant%20Vector%20Calculus.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

$*$ is the [Hodge star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator).

$♭$ is the [musical isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism).

In this particular case, this amounts to

\begin{align*}
(F_1,F_2,F_3)&\stackrel{♭}{\rightarrow}F_1dx_1+F_2dx_2+F_3dx_3 \\
&\stackrel{*}{\rightarrow}F_1dx_2dx_3-F_2dx_1dx_3+F_3dx_1dx_2 \\
&\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}\partial_1F_1dx_1dx_2dx_3+\partial_2F_2dx_1dx_2dx_3+\partial_3F_3dx_1dx_2dx_3  \\
&\stackrel{*} {\rightarrow}\partial_1F_1+\partial_2F_2+\partial_3F_3,  
\end{align*}
as you can check in the definitions given in the links above.